# Why can't i use steam?

Tags: steam

Alright so I checked all over the internet and was told to do `sudo apt-get install steam`, and it downloaded except then it said I needed some debian packages that I already have, closed out and left me out not able to use it.

I tried using the debian package on the site, and that did nothing when I clicked on it.

And searching steam on the USC didnt let me download it, does this mean my only chance is to download the Windows version through WINE?

When I run `steam` in a terminal I get this error

```
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically [2015-10-08 15:55:59] Startup - updater built Aug 19 2015 11:27:40 SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred X Error of failed request: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
```

Comment: How about telling us what these "packages you already have" are, then, open a terminal and run `steam` and post the errors here.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying on what packages I have, but they are the following:              libbz2.so.1.0                     libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0   libxtst so 6, and       libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0

Comment: Please open a terminal and enter `steam` and press enter, then add any errors here please and I will reopen your question.

Comment: Running Steam on ubuntu 15.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
[2015-10-08 15:55:59] Startup - updater built Aug 19 2015 11:27:40
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)                                   This is what I see.